Обновление строки в Postgresql
Мне нужно чтобы код срабатывал только 1 раз, то есть если несколько совпадений  только 1
Пример
Запись в бд
chat_id      order_name
32123        хлеб; хлеб; хлеб; хлеб; хлеб;
number_text = хлеб;
Результат chat_id order_name 32123 хлеб; хлеб; хлеб; хлеб;
cursor.execute( f"UPDATE cl_t SET order_name = REPLACE(order_name, '{number_text};', ''), " f"amount = amount - {cena} WHERE chat_id = {chat_id} AND status = 1" ) conn.commit()

replace() безусловно заменяет все вхождения заданной подстроки. Используйте regexp_replace(), для неё можно указать и количество замен, и позицию.

Спасибо, мне это помогло
